# "Non-numeric argument to binary operator error" when making a grouped boxplot

Tags: r, matrix, boxplot

I am trying to create a grouped boxplot using a fairly simple, but long dataset called `trch`.

First I used `trchtrue<- trch[complete.cases(trch), ]` to create a matrix with two columns and no 'NaN' values.

```
> head(trchtrue)
  REACH  WTEMP
2     1 11.090
3     2 11.120
4     3 11.200
5     4  9.334
6     5  9.556
7     6  9.263

> tail(trchtrue)
        REACH WTEMP
1342315    99 0.100
1342316   100 5.131
1342317   101 0.100
1342318   102 0.100
1342319   103 0.100
1342321   105 4.994
```

When trying to create a grouped box plot using `boxplot(trchtrue$REACH~trchtrue$WTEMP)`,  I get the following error:

```
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

With the exception of the column titles, all of the values appear to be numeric, however, I get this result:

```
is.numeric(trchtrue)
[1] FALSE
```

I am not able to convert the matrix to numeric either.

```
> as.numeric(trchtrue)
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> mode(trchtrue) = "numeric"
Error in mde(x) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I convert this matrix to numeric so I can make the box plot?

EDIT: In the original dataset, the values were in E notation. Could this be part of the problem?

EDIT 2: Here is the reprex.

```r
boxplot(trchtrue$REACH~trchtrue$WTEMP)
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'trchtrue' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Your boxplot says `trchtrue$TEMP` but `head(trchtrue)` says `WTEMP`   Did you just leave off the W?

Comment: @G5W Fixed. It still has the same error though.

Comment: Hi can you please provide a reproducible example? Thanks

Comment: @TTL Sorry, I wasn't sure what reprex was until now. I have added it to the post.

Comment: Hi Michael, why don't you try the following? I'm happy to write a better answer if that works. boxplot(as.numeric(as.character(trchtrue$REACH))~as.numeric(as.character(ttrchtrue$WTEMP)))

Comment: @CRP This seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Mi Michael, please accept my answer below if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another potential solution. First, transform each column to numeric. Next, plot the boxplot for the target columns.

```
trchtrue <- sapply( trchtrue, as.numeric )
boxplot(trchtrue$REACH~trchtrue$WTEMP)
```

Sometimes the `as.character` function is also requiered within `as.numeric`. This can solve the issue is the code above creates `NA`s

```
trchtrue[] <- lapply(trchtrue, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Good luck!